# In Angular how do you pass the innerText or innerHtml to a component

Tags: angular

I see from the docs that you can use @input to pass a property value to the component.

However how can you pass the innerText to the component so that one can do something like this?

```
<error-label>this is required"</error-label>
```

and pass the inner text to the component.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Can you please elaborate on the use case?

Comment: It's mostly for curiosity - but it's also because it is easier to type string values in the innerText than as a property.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a tempalte variable to create a reference and access it from within the template

```
<div #myDiv>foo</div>
<button (click)="sendInnerText(myDiv.innerText)">pass inner text</div>
```

or the component

```
@ViewChild('myDiv') divRef:ElementRef;

ngAfterViewInit() {
  console.log(this.div.nativeElement.innerText);
}
```

Comment: So what's the downvote for? You could post a better answer if you're so smart.